# open a downloaded pdf file in a new window

Tags: c#

When I was using the below code for downloading apdf file, a dialog box will appears having open,save,and cancel buttons. If I click 'open' button,the pdf file will be opened in the same window.

```
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";         
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Concat("inline;filename= " + filename + ""));
    Response.TransmitFile("D:\\local\\Projects\\intranet\\Intranet\\Intranet\\Intranet\\PaySlip\\" + filename + ".pdf");
    Response.End();                
}
```

Now,how can I opened the pdf file in a new window? Can I opened the file in another window by changing the code?

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

The link should have something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="document.pdf" Target="_blank"
Text="Open document in a new window"  runat="server"/>
```

Comment: excuse me,i'm new in this.so if you don't mind,could you please explain in detail?